# Internet sharing between windows 7 (connected over wifi) and unbuntu (tethered over mobile phone)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, wireless-networking

Here is my setup. I have a Windows 7 PC connected to internet over WiFi and would like to share this with Ubuntu (no router involved). Also, Ubuntu i use it for tethering for mobile data (whenever WiFi is down) and would like to use this connection from windows 7.
  I know hotspot is an option to get the mobile device to share the internet connection, but was looking if there is a way to with out this. Does anybody know of such a setup?

Comment: Do you have Ethernet connections on both? If so, it's pretty simple to share the connection, if you confirm that I can get an answer up with some screens (though later today, so someone else may be able to get that up sooner).

Comment: Yes, I do have Ethernet connections although do not have a router yet.

Comment: I am confused by: "Windows 7 PC connected to internet over WiFi" but no router yet.  Is the Ethernet unused in both machines?

Comment: Sorry to be vague. What i meant is  I cannot connect windows PC and Ubuntu to a router. Yes, Ethernet is unused on both machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for taking a bit to be back:

---

**Share from Ubuntu**

1. Click the Network Icon (mine: [image: wifi])
2. Click `Edit`

[image: edit]

3. Highlight your `Wired Connection` (It's your ethernet), select `Edit`

[image: edit]

4. Select the `IPv4 Settings` tab, change the "Method" to `Shared to other computers`

[image: shared]

Then all you need to do is connect an Ethernet between Ubuntu and whatever computer/object with an Ethernet that needs connectivity. Should have all the other settings already in place for that.